# Why blank redirect page from Magento to PayPal standard?

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7

I'm setting up Magento Multiple Stores (sub directory style, each store is www.domain.net/store) and trying to integrate PayPal standard. I've setup the account and configured the Magento side in the Default so all the stores use the same PayPal account.

Problem: When I try paying, the last step in the shopping cart (when the client has given all the data) results in a blank page: http://www.domain.net/store/paypal/standard/redirect/

Also, when I return to the store (no sale went through), the cart is empty.

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Problem solved. For whatever reason I had disabled Mage_Paypal in System / Configuration / Advanced / Advanced. It's working perfectly now.

Thanks and hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I think you just saved me an awful lot of time :)

Comment: Yes..! Its the same for V 1.8.1